# Exec SQL error because of single quotes inside

Tags: sql

I have the following exec query:

```
EXEC (
        'SELECT (SELECT Count(*) AS Count_Id FROM ns_customer WHERE external_id IN (
        ' RW00363075 ',' RW00336566 ',' RW00365438 ',' RW00343570 ')  ) AS Count_Id, 
        ACH_allowed, CC_allowed, DD_allowed FROM ns_customer 
        WHERE external_id IN (' RW00363075 ',' RW00336566 ',' RW00365438 ',
        ' RW00343570 ')'
        );
```

After execution I get an error:

> SQL statement: Incorrect syntax near 'RW00363075'.; Caused by:
>   Incorrect syntax near 'RW00363075'.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Use double single quotes?

Comment: when you putting strings together, you need to have plus(+) sign between them, like this select 'select ' + ' test'

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  It seems to be SQL Server based on the code and the error message.

Comment: Why are you exec-ing this, there are no variable identifiers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escape single quotes with two single quotes

```
EXEC('SELECT (SELECT Count(*) AS Count_Id FROM ns_customer WHERE external_id IN (''RW00363075'',''RW00336566'',''RW00365438'',''RW00343570'')  ) AS Count_Id, ACH_allowed, CC_allowed, DD_allowed FROM ns_customer 
    WHERE external_id IN (''RW00363075'',''RW00336566'',''RW00365438'',''RW00343570'')');
```

Comment: Great. This fixed my problem. Any idea why it is using a escape backslash `\'` ? I have been trying this on SQL SERVER but it would store the backslash as an entry. 
E.g. `\'RW00363075\'`

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your specific question is to double up the single quotes.  However, (assuming that you are using SQL Server), your query would be more simply written as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () as Count_Id, ACH_allowed, CC_allowed, DD_allowed
FROM ns_customer 
WHERE external_id IN ('RW00363075', 'RW00336566', 'RW00365438', 'RW00343570')
```

Or, as I prefer, use `sp_executesql`:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = '
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () as Count_Id, ACH_allowed, CC_allowed, DD_allowed
FROM ns_customer 
WHERE external_id IN (''RW00363075'', ''RW00336566'', ''RW00365438'', ''RW00343570'')';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

If you are going to learn how to do this, you might as well learn the right way.  `sp_executesql` is superior to `exec()` because it allows you to pass parameters in and out of the query.  Learning to use it first is simpler than learning it later.

Comment: May be he can use `REPLACE` to escape single quote (if using SQL Servee), @Gordon Linoff. So he can use this construct with other SQL commands which contain single quote.